# Is it a bad idea to include Docker-Compose alongside Kubernetes, Minikube and Skaffold on your team's dev enviroment?

Tags: kubernetes, docker-compose, minikube, volumes, skaffold

Ideally, we would only want to stick to Minikube and Scaffold.

But there are many cases in which we would like to enable 2-way syncing of volumes so that changes in a specific container directory are reflected on a directory of the host machine.

We currently use kubectl to copy directories and files manually from the pod unto a local directory. But we would like to automate this step.

Docker-Compose makes it very easy to set this up by defining a rw volume to a service:

```
services:
  myService:
    image: some/image
    volumes:
      - /some-host/path:/some-container/path:rw
```

So whenever we need to reflect changes into our local environment, we would stop skaffold, start docker-compose, and make the changes necessary on the container so that they are automatically reflected locally.

The issue is that if we want to make a change to one of the services in the system we now have to reflect these changes on our k8s deployments, as well as our docker-compose file. These would include reflecting changes to secrets, config maps, etc... and we might end up with a really complicated project.

Is this a bad idea? Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look into [Tilt](https://tilt.dev/) or [Telepresence](https://www.telepresence.io/). We currently are working on changing our local development environment from docker-compose to a microk8s based approach and are looking into those two approaches, as we are too facing the issue of shared volumes which are not supported out of the box in microk8s.

Just an idea, we will have to see ourselves what solution works best for us :)

Comment: Thank you for sharing, I will consider those two options. I also found KSync, which seems to do exactly what I need. I just need to confirm that it works, and that there is an easy way of setting it up. https://github.com/ksync/ksync